# SharePoint 2013 CSOM: Is it better to pass a Context object around or a Url?

Tags: client-object-model, best-practices

In SharePoint 2013 CSOM is it better to pass a Context object around, or a Url to open a context?

Which would be the best example:
*(Please consider there may be a lot of methods preforming tasks)*

1) Pass Context, open Web

```
EnableSomethingOnWeb(ClientContext ctx, bool enable){
   ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
   // enable something
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}

var ctx = new ClientContext("http://myweb");
EnableSomethingOnWeb(ctx, true);
```

2) Pass Url, open ClientContext, Open web

```
EnableSomethingOnWeb(string Url, bool enable){
   var ctx = new ClientContext(Url);
   ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
   // enable something
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}

EnableSomethingOnWeb(webUrl, true);
```

3) Pass Web, Execute ClientContext

```
EnableSomethingOnWeb(Web web, bool enable){

   // enable something
   web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
}

var ctx = new ClientContext("http://myweb");
ctx.Load(ctx.Web);

EnableSomethingOnWeb(ctx.Web, true);
*keep in mind following calls may continue pass this web object around.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Do:**

- Pass around `ClientContext`.
- Call `.ExecuteQuery()` as few times as possible, bundle/batch up with `.Load()`.

  - Once is usually enough, only in a very few cases do you need more.

**Do not:**

- Do not pass around `Web`.

  - You need to reference other members from `ClientContext`, such as `Site`.
- Do not pass around an URL (either as `String` or `Uri`).

  - Initialization method of `ClientContext` can alternate, e.g., provider hosted apps use this: `SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext).CreateUserC‌​lientContextForSPHost()`.

Also:
I usually make "Repository" classes, which work on `ClientContext` without actually calling `.ExecuteQuery()`, so I bundle up (batch) `.Load` commands and fire them on the "outside", then come back to the Repository.

```
public class ListAndViewRepository
{
    private readonly ListCollection _lists;
    public List<List> Lists { get; set; }
    public List<View> Views { get; set; }

    public ListAndViewRepository(ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        _lists = clientContext.Web.Lists;
        clientContext.Load(_lists,
            collection =>
                collection.Include(l => l.Id, l => l.Title,
                    l => l.Views.Include(v => v.Id, v => v.Title, v => v.ViewFields, v => v.ViewQuery)));
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Lists = _lists.ToList();
        Views = Lists.SelectMany(list => list.Views.ToList()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Used something like this:

```
var listAndViewRepository = new ListAndViewRepository(clientContext);
// ... do a lot of other "repositories"
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
// ... call "Execute" on other "repositories"
listAndViewRepository .Execute();
var lists = listAndViewRepository.Lists;
var views = listAndViewRepository.Views;
```

Comment: So to clarify, constructing class libraries should use "ClientContext" because of multiple ways to init the object may cause inconsistencies?

Comment: @ElliotWood: Yes, they should not initialize the object. In provider hosted apps you do something like `SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext).CreateUserClientContextForSPHost()` instead of just `new ClientContext`.

Comment: Could you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893774/how-to-manage-client-context-object-in-seperate-class-library

Answer (score 5):

Objects like `Web`, `ClientContext` are passed by reference, that is they are not copied. So there is no need to worry about performance. However, as mentioned by @eirikb, pasing `ClientContext` between methods make more sense as you can then load whatever objects you want from it inside the method.

Comment: Note that when you initializing a new instance of `ClientContext` it will validate the URL, so at least 10 nanoseconds to save there. Although when initializing in a provider hosted app the overhead is much much larger

Comment: @eirikb, so it is good to initialize `ClientContext` once and then pass between methods rather than passing url and initializing inside the method.

Comment: @Nadeem So by ref would imply you could get the context and call other things by going: var ctx = web.Context; ctx.Load(...)??

Comment: @ElliotWood, That is right. However, if `ClientContext` is passed instead of `Web` then there is no need to do `var ctx = web.Context`